# AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/enough_platform_widgets-0.7.4/lib/src/platform/decorated_platform_textfield.dart:536:20:

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets-3.3.5/lib/src/platform_text_field.dart:578:30: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
enabled: data?.enabled ?? enabled,
^
../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/enough_platform_widgets-0.7.4/lib/src/platform/decorated_platform_textfield.dart:536:20: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
enabled: enabled,
^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\nadya\development\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).

how to solve this problem